# How to change the color of a shape's body in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

*This question is about Microsoft Visio 2013 (German).*

I'm using several standard shapes with standard coloring, but now I would like to change one of the shape's colors. I know how to change colors :), but this shape consists of different parts.

My storage symbol is a `can` shape (DE: `Dose`) from `Standard Shapes` stencil. When I choose the *fill color* and change it, only the lid is colored in my selected color... Unfortunately, my color (dark gray) is not listed in the design templates.

**How can I change the body color?**

[image: my SSD symbol]

I can't find any option in the "shape formatting options" to select different parts of the shape:

[image]
(clickable)

Answer (score 3):

There a two parts to this shape ('Can' in 'Basic Shapes') - The group (top-level) shape, which holds the Ellipse geometry, and a single child sub-shape, which holds the geometry form the sides.  You can see, and select, the various parts in the Drawing Explorer (which you may have to [turn on Developer Mode](http://www.visguy.com/2008/08/04/top-9-reasons-for-turning-on-developer-mode/) to see).

[image: Visio Drawing Explorer]

By default, when you apply a fill color, or some other format, to a group shape all of the child shapes will receive the same setting, however if you select the sub-shape (Sheet.2 in the image) you can apply formating just to that shape.  So you'll need to first, set to color on the group shape, and then select the sub-shape and choose another color for that.

Note that any subsequent changes made to the group shape will of course be applied to the child shapes again.  If you want to lock your sub-shape to a specific color, you can set protection on it by first selecting the sub-shape in the Drawing Explorer and then showing Protection dialog and checking 'from group formatting' checkbox.

[image]